# I've been struggling with "無理させて... ごめんね..."

Tags: grammar, translation, japanese-to-english

I tried to read it many times and the google translation didn't make sense, so I wanted ask if anyone here knew what this means. This something that red person made green person to do, that green didn't want to do but had no choice to wear it. Then green said "I'm at my limit"

Red person: "無理させて... ごめんね..."  = I went too far...I'm sorry... / I overreacted... I'm sorry...

I'm asking here because google showed me "I'm sorry for making you unreasonable" and then "i'm sorry for forcing you"

I just started learning Japanese btw >.< Thank you~

Comment: I'm assuming the red person said 「無理させてごめんね」...?

Comment: Yeah, red person said it (I'm sorry I just realized I didn't put that there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[無理をする](https://jisho.org/search/muriwosuru) means to do something past your own limits (often in a bad way). させる is the causative of する. So, 無理をさせる is the causative of 無理をする, meaning "to cause someone to do something past their own limits".

The red person is apologizing for "making the green person force themselves past their limits". If it is some kind of request the red person made, then maybe it could be translated as "sorry for making such an impossible request".

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining and also I didn't know you can edit my post and fixed a few grammar mistakes. (I'm not English native but I'm still learning English grammar)

Comment: @Anya-chan no problem :)